# Pass column name as argument?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to pass a column name as an argument into a function?

I would like to create a function whereby I filter values based upon a column, but I pass this column name into the function (ideally as a string)?

I did try but I declared the column name as a varchar and obviously this wouldnt work!

Comment: You can pass the column name in as a string OK. But you can't use dynamic SQL in functions so you would need conditional logic to handle all cases.

Comment: You may be able to do it in a CLR compiled user function, but that's a bunch of work which is probably not a good use of your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The only way to do that is with Dynamic SQL.  It's not uncommon to make a Stored Procedure that takes field/table names as parameters, and builds a new SQL statement to execute.

Functions, however, can't execute Dynamic SQL.

This *may* be an indication of a mis-directed design.  If you elaborate on why you need this, we may be able to offer alternative designs where it's not needed at all.

Or, you may be better suited with a Stored Procedure than a function.

The idea of using a chain of `OR` conditions *does* also meet something like your description.  But it normally generates very bad plans.  I'll look up my useful link for an explanation of why and how to deal with it; it's very in depth, but very good to know.

**EDIT** Here's the link:  [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 2):

you could do it in some dynamic sql, where you build a query on the fly, or if you have a limited number of fields you could do something like

```
select * from table where
(param = 'field1' and field1 = value)
or (param = 'field2' and field2 = value)
```